# Crear url amigable con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Estoy creando una web personal, en la que voy a tener solo una página indice con diferentes idiomas. Tengo 3 enlaces que me llaman por parámetro al indice pasándole el idioma:

```
<li class="lang"><a href="index.php?lang=en">EN</a></li>
<li class="lang"><a href="index.php?lang=es">ES</a></li>
<li class="lang"><a href="index.php?lang=ca">CA</a></li>
```

Y estoy creando un archivo .htaccess que segun el idioma que venga por parámetro me añada un /es /en o /ca al final del nombre de la web. Ahora mismo lo que tengo en el archivo .htaccess es esto:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.)?$ index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(es|en)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Si introduzco el nombre/es o /en o /ca me redirige bien y me muestra la web en ese idioma, pero si clico en los enlaces de la página me aparece el

```
index.php?lang=es
```

No sé si es por estar trabajando en localhost, o es que debo cambiar algo en las reglas pero por más que busco no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar.

Gracias

Comment: Haz probado: `<a href="/en"> ... <a href="/es"> ....` ?

Comment: tus enlaces ya no deben ser asi, sino como dices q los introduces, como indica @aldanux

Comment: Gracias @aldanux, al final tenía que ponerlos así, solo el idioma "en" o "es".

Answer (score 0):

Como he indicado en los comentarios, gracias a @aldanux he solucionado mi problema cambiando las urls de los enlaces a los idiomas dejando solo el valor del parámetro de la url, tal que así:

```
<li class="lang"><a href="en">EN</a></li>
<li class="lang"><a href="es">ES</a></li>
<li class="lang"><a href="ca">CA</a></li>
```